# Efficient data sampling with sparse timestamps on a pre-defined date range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, resampling

Consider a dataframe with sparse temporal data. The timestamps can be very old (e.g. years ago) or very recent.

As an example, let's take the following dataframe:

```
                    tstamp     item_id   budget
2016-07-01 14:56:51.882649  0Szr8SuNbY  5000.00
2016-07-20 14:57:23.856878  0Szr8SuNbY  5700.00
2016-07-17 16:32:27.838435  0Lzu1xOM87   303.51
2016-07-30 21:50:03.655102  0Lzu1xOM87    94.79
2016-08-01 14:56:31.081140  0HzuoujTsN   100.00
```

Say we need to **resample** this dataframe **for each `item_id`** so that we get a **dense** dataframe that has one data point for every day for a **pre-defined date range**, using a **forward fill**.

In other words, if I resample the above for the time interval

```
pd.date_range(date(2016,7,15), date(2016,7,31)
```

I should get:

```
        date     item_id   budget
  2016-07-15  0Szr8SuNbY  5000.00
  2016-07-16  0Szr8SuNbY  5000.00
  2016-07-17  0Szr8SuNbY  5000.00
  ...
  2016-07-31  0Szr8SuNbY  5000.00
  2016-07-15  0Lzu1xOM87      NaN
  2016-07-16  0Lzu1xOM87      NaN
  2016-07-17  0Lzu1xOM87   303.51
  ...
  2016-07-31  0Lzu1xOM87    94.79
  2016-07-15  0HzuoujTsN      NaN
  2016-07-16  0HzuoujTsN      NaN
  2016-07-17  0HzuoujTsN      NaN
  ...
  2016-07-31  0HzuoujTsN      NaN
```

Note that the original dataframe contains sparse timestamps and a potentially very **high number** of unique `item_id`s. In other words, I am hoping to find a **computational efficient** way of resampling this data with daily frequency on a pre-defined time period of consideration.

What's the best we can do in Pandas, numpy, or Python in general?

Comment: you can now do this directory in 0.19.0 (coming soon); http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0190-enhancements-rolling-ts and see linked docs

Comment: Thanks @Jeff ! I can use the version in `master`. How exactly would you solve this problem with `rolling` (or some other method?)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `groupby` on `'item_id'` and call [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on each group:

```
# Define the new time interval.
new_dates = pd.date_range('2016-07-15', '2016-07-31', name='date')

# Set the current time stamp as the index and perform the groupby.
df = df.set_index(['tstamp'])
df = df.groupby('item_id').apply(lambda grp: grp['budget'].reindex(new_dates, method='ffill').to_frame())

# Reset the index to remove 'item_id' and 'date' from the index.
df = df.reset_index()
```

Another option is to `pivot`, `reindex`, and `unstack`:

```
# Define the new time interval.
new_dates = pd.date_range('2016-07-15', '2016-07-31', name='date')

# Pivot to have 'item_id' columns with 'budget' values.
df = df.pivot(index='tstamp', columns='item_id', values='budget').ffill()

# Reindex with the new dates.
df = df.reindex(new_dates, method='ffill')

# Unstack and reset the index to return to the original format.
df = df.unstack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'budget'})
```